# SQL Server trigger that launches an external script file

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, triggers

I've written a trigger that on update or insert launches a script. However when the trigger runs it ends up locking up my database and I have to do a restart to be able to run queries again. I'm not seeing anything in the trigger that would cause this.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[CALCULATEDFIELDS]
ON  [dbo].[custom_values]
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS 
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @CUSTOMIZED_ID VARCHAR(15)

    SELECT @CUSTOMIZED_ID = (SELECT customized_id FROM inserted)

    BEGIN
        DECLARE @OUTSTRING varchar(300)

        BEGIN
            IF NOT @CUSTOMIZED_ID IS NULL
                SELECT @OUTSTRING = '\\DRIVE\Folder\Script.vbs '+ @CUSTOMIZED_ID
            ELSE
                SELECT @OUTSTRING = '\\DRIVE\Folder\Script.vbs '+ @CUSTOMIZED_ID

            EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @OUTSTRING, NO_OUTPUT
        END
    END
```

Comment: Your trigger has **MAJOR** flaw in that you seem to assume it'll be called **once per row** - that is **not** the case. The trigger will fire **once per statement**, so if your `INSERT` statement that causes this trigger to fire inserts 25 rows, you'll get the trigger fired **once**, but then `Inserted` pseudo table will contain 25 rows. Which of those 25 rows will your code select here?? `SELECT customized_id FROM inserted` - it's non-deterministic, you'll get **one arbitrary row** and you will be **ignoring all other rows**. You need to rewrite your trigger to take this into account!

Comment: Would it matter in the case that the "customized_id" row will be the same for every row that's inserted? I actually only need to grab that value when an update or insert is done.

Answer (score 0):

The following statement does not make any sense:

```
SELECT @CUSTOMIZED_ID = (SELECT customized_id FROM inserted)
```

And should actually end up in an error like this:

```
Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
```

This way it should make more sense (as your customized_id is always the same):

```
SELECT TOP 1 @CUSTOMIZED_ID = customized_id FROM inserted
```

To your "blocking" problem:

Did you try to run your update (and trigger) without starting the script?

```
-- EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @OUTSTRING, NO_OUTPUT
```

Does your update work? If yes, it looks like your script execute is too long or you have any kind of other problem. Does your script gets executed after the update? Did you check that?

Further, why do you do the following? You call the script anyway in both cases, or am i wrong?

```
IF NOT @CUSTOMIZED_ID IS NULL
```

Comment: So I actually made your first change before. What I also realized was that I stupidly left msgbox in my script which was likely causing it to never complete

Comment: apparently it still isn't working, must be some further problems. To test the script I launched it through the query window, it completed and returned NULL as I would expect. I then removed the else since it was redundant and commented out the execution of the script, the update succeeded. Now to figure out why the EXEC line doesn't work within the trigger but works fine outside of it.

Comment: Can you post the update script with which the trigger is getting triggered? Can you also change your vbs script to nothing in order to see whether the script is called by the trigger correctly (and does nothing). In that case, you would be sure that the trigger works fine and the script gets called correctly, but then you know the inside of the script has a problem.

Comment: the update gets triggered by a web application called Redmine, I'm not sure I can get the actual statement that it runs. I'll try emptying my script and running it that way.

Comment: I was not able to figure out why the trigger ran indefinitely, I ended up just rewriting the script as the trigger itself which took less time than I spent troubleshooting why I couldn't get the script to launch.